# write блокирует текущий поток при попытке записать что-либо в мастер pty

Tags: c++, linux, c

Создаю мастера и раба с помощью `openpty(&master, &slave, name, NULL, NULL)` после чего использую master как поток вывода и записываю большое количество инфы с помощью write. Проблема в том, что при достижении некоего лимита (по видимому заполнение буффера) write блокирует текущий поток пока из slave не будет прочитана информация. Информация быстро устаревает и меня такое поведение программы не устраивает: если информация не была прочитана, то она должна быть просто проигнорирована. Как это сделать?

Comment: организуйте запрос-ответ. Та сторона присылает запрос, а Вы присылаете ответ. Если никто ничего не просит, то и слать не нужно.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы новые или самые старые данные пропадали, если нет места?

Comment: Спасибо, уже нашел ответ

Answer (score 0):

Собственно нашел решение порывшись немного в документации. Для того чтобы write не блокировал поток необходимо поставить мастер в non-blocking mode. Для этого можно использовать функцию `fcntl`:

```cpp
int flags = fcntl(master, F_GETFL, 0);
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(master, F_SETFL, flags);
```

Comment: правда у Вас будут другие проблемы. Но думаю, Вы их решите

Comment: @KoVadim не подскажите какие?

Comment: например, когда Ваша функция записи не может записать, она будет возвращать специальный код ошибки. Также она может записать не все данные и если Ваши данные структурированные (а не побайтные), то нужно будет уметь корректно дописать хвост.

Comment: @KoVadim ясно, спасибо

Comment: Ну часто с `write()`, `read()` люди забывают о сигналах... там целый спектр ошибок надо проверять, да и `close()` вообще-то тоже может не выполниться, а это не проверяется в 99% программ...